# Need to understand the fundamentals of pattern matching using generics

Tags: f#

I need help understanding the concepts behind the following:

I have this:

```
type Result<'TSuccess,'TFailure> = 
    | Success of 'TSuccess
    | Failure of 'TFailure
```

But this doesn't work:

```
let getRequest = function
    | Success input -> input 
    | Failure msg -> msg
```

But this does:

```
let getRequest result = 
    match result with
    | Success input -> input 
    | Failure msg -> failwithf "Invalid input: %s" msg
```

Why does the initial "getRequest" fail?

Again, I just don't understand the basic rules for pattern matching.
Can someone please shed some light on this?

The entire code is here:

```
module Core

type Result<'TSuccess,'TFailure> = 
    | Success of 'TSuccess
    | Failure of 'TFailure

let bind nextFunction lastFunctionResult = 
    match lastFunctionResult with
    | Success input -> nextFunction input
    | Failure f -> Failure f

type Request = {Name:string; Email:string}

let validate1 input =
   if input.Name = "" then Failure "Name must not be blank"
   else Success input

let validate2 input =
   if input.Name.Length > 50 then Failure "Name must not be longer than 50 chars"
   else Success input

let validate3 input =
   if input.Email = "" then Failure "Email must not be blank"
   else Success input;;

let Validate = 
    validate1 
    >> bind validate2 
    >> bind validate3;;

// Setup
let goodInput = {Name="Alice"; Email="abc@abc.com"}
let badInput = {Name=""; Email="abc@abc.com"};;

let getRequest = function
    | Success input -> input 
    | Failure msg -> msg

// Test
let result = Validate goodInput;;
let request = getRequest result;;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  The compiler certainly accepts your first definition of `getRequest`, but it constrains the success and failure types to be the same (because the return type needs to be well defined), so it can't be used with the output of `Validate`.

Comment: Is there some link or a book to figure out how pattern matching works with types? I really need some simplified answer that I'm able to digest.

Comment: Start here: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question actually gives a good platform to explain pattern matching.

Let's start by thinking about the types involved, your `getRequest` function must be a function with some type signature `getRequest : 'a -> 'b'`, i.e. it takes something of one type and returns something of another but let's look at what you've written.

```
let getRequest = 
    function
    | Success input -> input // this branch would return 'TSuccess
    | Failure msg -> msg // this brach would return 'TFailure
```

*You can't have a function whose type signature is `'a -> 'b or 'c`.*  (The only way to make this function compile is if `'b` and `'c` can be constrained to be the same type, then we do simply have a consistent `'a -> 'b`).

But wait, enter the discriminated union.

Your discriminated union has type `Result<'TSuccess,'TFailure>`.  Or, to describe things as I did above type `'d<'b,'c>`.  Now, *we absolutely can have a function whose type signature is `'a -> 'd<'b,'c>`.*

`'d<'b, 'c>` is just a generic type which involves `'b` and it involves `'c`.  The type signature includes all of these things, so hopefully you can see that we can contain both a `'TSuccess` and `'TFailure` in this type with no problem.

So, if we want to return something which can contain different combinations of types, we've found the perfect use case for the discriminated union.  It can contain the `'TSuccess` or the `'TFailure` in one type.  You can then choose between those results using pattern matching.

```
let getRequest = 
    function
    | Success input -> printfn "%A" input // do something with success case
    | Failure msg -> printfn "%A" msg // do something with failure case
```

So long as we have consistent return types in each case, we can insert any behaviour we want.

On to the next point of why throwing an exception is okay.  Let's look at the type signature of the `failwithf` function: `failwithf : StringFormat<'T,'Result> -> 'T`.  The `failwithf` function takes a string format and returns some type `'T`.

So let's look at your second function again

```
let getRequest result = 
    match result with
    | Success input -> input // type 'TSuccess
    | Failure msg -> failwithf "Invalid input: %s" msg // type 'T inferred to be 'TSuccess
```

The function signature is consistent, `'a -> 'TSuccess`.

Comment: The function signature is maybe consistent but its lying. As you may throw an exception in there, it may then absolutely NOT return a 'TSuccess. The second part is that the whole point of Result<'TSuccess,'TFailure> is to remove exceptions. Not create them.

Comment: @HelgeReneUrholm I was explaining why the above function compiles (since that was part of the question!) not making any kind of recommendation in favour of that code.

Comment: this is quite ok explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34122575/5514938 A question may not necessarily be answered as a direct answer to the question. Especially not when the premisse of the questions is wrong, or the answer does not entirely cover those premisses. In short: Mu. Nimrod wants to learn programming. Not solving a specific (non-)issue.

Answer (score 3):

Given this definition

```
let getRequest = function
| Success input -> input 
| Failure msg -> msg
```

we can reason about its type as follows:

1. Since it's a function, it has type `?1 -> ?2` for some not-yet-known placeholder types.
2. The input uses the `Success` and `Failure` union cases, so the input must itself actually be some type `Result<?3,?4>`, and the function's type is `Result<?3,?4> -> ?2`.
3. The types of each branch must be the same as the function's return type.

   1. Looking at the first branch, we see this means that `?3` = `?2`.
   2. Looking at the second branch, this means that `?4` = `?2`.

   Therefore the overall type of the function must be `Result<?2,?2> -> ?2`, or using real F# notation, `Result<'a,'a> -> 'a` where `'a` can be any type - this is a generic function definition.

But `Validate` has type `Request -> Result<Request, string>`, so its output isn't consistent with this definition of `getResult` because the success and failure types are different and you can't just directly pass the results from one to the other.

On the other hand, with

```
let getRequest = function
| Success input -> input 
| Failure msg -> failwithf "Invalid input: %s" msg
```

we would analyze it like this:

1. As before, any function has type `?1 -> ?2`.
2. As before, the input must clearly be a `Result<?3,?4>`.
3. But analyzing the branches, we get a different result:

   1. The first branch again leads to the constraint `?3` = `?2`.
   2. But the second branch is different - `failwithf` with that format pattern takes a string and throws an exception (and can have any return type, since it never returns normally), so we see `msg` must be a string, so `?4` = `string`.

   So the overall type is `Result<'a,string> -> 'a`, which now allows you to pass a `Result<Request,string>` to it, as desired.