# Unable to resolve error regarding "option" when retrieving value from tuple

Tags: f#

I just don't understand what the compiler is trying to tell me here:

```
let someCard = getFirstCard hand
```

**Error:**

> This expression was expected to have type
>         `Card * Card`
>     but here has type
>         `(Card * Card) option`

I then tried this:

```
let getFirstCard (hand:Card*Card) = function
    | card1, card2 -> Some(card1)
```

But I get the same error.

I just don't get the Options template.
I continue to struggle with this.

My code is below:

```
type Suit = | Spades| Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts

type Face = | Two | Three | Four | Five 
            | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
            | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type Card = {Face:Face; Suit:Suit}

type Deal = | Hand of Card * Card
            | Hit of Card

let private suits = [Spades; Clubs; Diamonds ; Hearts]
let private faces = [Two; Three; Four; Five; Six; Seven; Eight; Nine; Ten;
                     Jack; Queen; King; Ace]

let deck = [for suit in suits do
                for face in faces do
                    yield {Face=face; Suit=suit}]

let hitPlayer (deck:Card list) =
    (deck.Head, deck.Tail)

let shuffle xs =
    let swap i j (array : _[]) =
        let tmp = array.[i]
        array.[i] <- array.[j]
        array.[j] <- tmp
    let rnd = System.Random()
    let xArray = Seq.toArray xs
    let n = Array.length xArray
    for i in [0..(n-2)] do
        let j = rnd.Next(i, n-1)
        swap i j xArray
    xArray |> Seq.toList

let deal = function
    | card1::card2::remaining -> Some(card1, card2), remaining
    | _ -> None, [];;

let getFirstCard (hand:Card*Card) = function
    | card1, card2 -> card1

let hand, deckRemaining = deal (shuffle deck);;
let someCard = getFirstCard hand
```

Comment: BTW, that `shuffle` function looks like it could be simpler. See here for alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33312260/126014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getFirstCard` function has the type `Card * Card -> 'a * 'b -> 'a` (which, BTW, looks strange, to say the least). It does, however, expect its first parameter to be of the type `Card * Card`.

`hand`, on the other hand (pun intended), has the type `(Card * Card) option`. This means that it *may* contain a `Card * Card` value, but it also may not. You'll need to tell your program how to deal with both cases.

As [we've discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34122575/126014), the Option type is an 'elevated world', and the most appropriate strategy is to stay in that elevated world until you can deal with all cases. Here's one way to do it:

```
let someCard = hand |> Option.map getFirstCard
```

This still doesn't work because of the weird implementation of `getFirstCard`.

Looking at the implementation of `getFirstCard`, though, I get the impression that what you attempt to do is to get the first card out of a tuple of cards. This, however, can be written as:

```
let getFirstCard (card1, card2) = card1
```

That function is already built into F#, although there's nothing wrong with giving it a domain-specific name. In that case, though, I'd suggest aliasing it instead:

```
let getFirstCard = fst
```

Given one of the two above definitions of `getFirstCard`, the expression

```
let someCard = hand |> Option.map getFirstCard
```

gives you a `someCard` value of the type `Card option`. You'll notice that we've stayed in the 'elevated' *Option* world.

Specifically, though, `someCard` has this value:

```
> someCard;;
val it : Card option = Some {Face = King;
                             Suit = Clubs;}
```

You'll note that it isn't just *King of Clubs*, but ***Some*** King of Clubs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
let getFirstCard (hand) = 
    match hand with 
    | Some(x) -> Some (fst x)
    |_ -> None

let hand, deckRemaining = deal (shuffle deck);;
let someCard = getFirstCard hand
```

It compiles & runs for me.

Actually, function getFirstCard could be renamed as a generic fun on tuples :

```
let getFirstOfTupleOption tup =
    match tup with
    | Some (x) -> Some (fst x)
    | _ -> None
```

Alternatively, you may want explicit type restriction on your domain with :

```
let getFirstCard (hand:(Card*Card) option) = 
    match hand with 
    | Some(x) -> Some (fst x)
    |_ -> None
```

Comment: Your definition of `getFirstCard` is equivalent to just `Option.map fst`.

Comment: Thanks Fyodor. It would be definitely be more elegant & succint. I still leave my answer unchanged and hope that OP will see your comment.